# Inspect FormData for remove an entry

Tags: javascript, ajax, form-data

I have a FormData object :

```
var form = jQuery("#options section.active form")[0];
var data = new FormData(form);
```

The form is really consequent, and before the ajax upload, I want to replace one of the entry (The goal is to take out an image and replace it with the same image, but resized and compressed), but I don't know how to know the key which are used for the image.
When I will know the key I would use `FormData.delete` and then `FormData.set`

If you know a better workaround for my problem, It's nice too, thanks.

Edit : I want to inspect the element in javascript like :

```
Console.log(data);
```

Comment: you could the element with its `#id` or `.classname` regard less of form.

Comment: You can't really inspect a formData object in the console, at least not so you see the values etc. Why not compress and resize the image on the server, it's usually a lot easier.

Comment: @adeneo I made a script which works really well, and I prefer resize the image BEFORE the upload, because I works with graphists who have the bad habit to upload really large files, so I prefer to work on the image in the client side.